# Contentful update field

Tags: reactjs, contentful

I want to update a field when a user clicks the specific image. I added an onClick method to the image, and the function is below.

I got a space.getEntry not a function error at the end.

```
makeFav = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
    client.getSpace('-').then((space) => space.getEntry(this.props.sys.id))
        .then((entry) => {
            entry.fields.favorited = true
            entry.update()
                .then(entry => console.log(entry.fields.favorited))
        })
}
```

Comment: What is your `getSpace` function doing ?

Comment: Which Contentful version are you using?

Comment: @Héctor "contentful": "^7.4.3" ..  getSpace is not my function, guess its needed to access my space

Comment: I think `space.getEntry` is deprecated from version 5.0. Maybe, you should use `space.getEnvironment().getSpace()`? https://contentful.github.io/contentful-management.js/contentful-management/5.7.0/ContentfulEnvironmentAPI.html#.getEntry

Comment: oh, i didnt think about that, i'll check that.  but for now `space.getEnvironment().getSpace()` gives me the same error

Comment: @paddyyy I meant using promises: `client.getSpace('spaceId').then(space => space.getEnvironment('environmentId')).then(environment => environment.getEntry())`

Comment: thx but this time i get space.getEnvironment is not a function, when i clicked on a image

Comment: 12 hours of sifting through docs and SO posts and still not any closer to understanding how to simply update a single Contentful field--like/dislike integers in this case--from a React app.